# what is the regexp pattern for multiline (logstash)

Tags: regex, tomcat, stack-trace, multiline, logstash

Currently I have:

```
multiline {
 type => "tomcat"
 pattern => "(^.+Exception: .+)|(^\s+at .+)|(^\s+... \d+ more)|(^\s*Caused by:.+)|(---)"
 what => "previous"
}
```

and this is part of my log:

```
TP-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
    at xxxxxx
Caused by: xxxxxxxxx
    at xxxxxx
Caused by: xxxxxxxxx   
--- The error occurred in xxxxxxxxx.  
--- The error occurred xxxxxxxxxx.
```

My pattern doesn't work here. Probably because i added the (---) at the end. What is the correct regexp to also add the --- lines?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to account for the other characters on the line as well:

```
(^---.*$)
```

Comment: Tried it but doesn't work. Also tried (^.---.+) and (^\-\-\-.*) and everything in between. I also can't find a logstash log telling me what the error is.

Comment: How about `(^---.+)`? Also, if you remove `(---)` from your original config does the expression work for the other lines that you would expect it to pick up?

Comment: If I remove (---) it works fine. (except for the -- lines :-P).

Also tried (^---.+) but did not worked.

Comment: This is a bit of a stretch but maybe try copying the '-' character directly from a log and pasting it into the regex? Maybe the hyphen in the log isn't the same encoding as the one in the regex. Could there be whitespace at the beginning of the lines with hyphens? Try `(^\s*---.*)` too.

Comment: @user3752671 Any luck or progress on this?

Answer (score 2):

I have put your regex and text into these online regex buddies and tried the suggestion of Eric:

- http://www.regextester.com/
- http://www.regexr.com/

Sometimes these online buddies really help to clear the mind. This picture shows what is recognized:

[image: Regex processing on regexr.com]

If I were stuck on this, I wouldn't focus on the regex itself any further. Rather I'd check these points:

- As there are different regex dialects, what dialect is used by logstash? What does it mean to my pattern?
- Are there any logstash specific modifiers that are not set and need to be set?
- As Ben mentioned, there are further filter tools. Would it help to use [grok](http://logstash.net/docs/1.1.0/filters/grok) instead?

Answer (score 1):

If one log event start with a timestamp or a specific word, for example, in your logs if all logs start with `TP`, then  you can use it as filter pattern.

```
    multiline {
            pattern => "^TP"
            what => "previous"
            negate => true
    }
```

With this filter you can multiline your logs easy, no need to use complex patterns.

Comment: Sometimes it is ^TP. Sometimes it is [Unloading and sometimes it is log4j: .

tried doing it like this "^TP|^\[Unloading|^log4j:" but isn't working

Comment: I think you have misunderstand it. The pattern "^TP" means all the logs start will "TP". The "^" means starting of a line at regexp. So, will your logs, "TPXXXXXXXX", all the logs can handle by logstash. You can try to modify your logs with all start with "TP". Then try it again. :)